# Checking User Roles to Display

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I recently added Identity to my ASP.NET project, but I'm having trouble checking user roles.

I originally create my Admin role in Startup.cs:

```
private void createRolesandUsers()
{
        ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
        var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));

        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Admin"))
        {

            var role = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole();
            role.Name = "Admin";
            roleManager.Create(role);

            var user = new ApplicationUser();
            user.UserName = "admin";
            user.Email = "admin@tpms.com";

            string userPWD = "********";

            var chkUser = UserManager.Create(user, userPWD);

            if (chkUser.Succeeded)
            {
                var result1 = UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
            }
        }
}
```

In my UserController.cs, I have a function to check if the user is an admin:

```
public Boolean isAdminUser()
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var user = User.Identity;
        ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
        var s = UserManager.GetRoles(user.GetUserId());
        if (s[0].ToString() == "Admin")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to access the isAdminUser() function from both my Views and my Controllers.

I've done a little bit of research the IsUserInRole() function, but when I tried:

```
@if (Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "Admin")) { Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.GuestID }); }
```

The if statement always returns false.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin");` as `Roles.IsUserInRole` related to old membership provider under [System.Web.Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security) namespace and need `roleManager` provider configuration in `web.config`.

```
@if(HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin")) 
{
    Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.GuestID });
}
```

Another way is to use `UserManager`

```
userManager.IsInRole("userId","Admin")
```

Comment: That didn't work, but I think you may be on to something.

I've noticed now that I have 2 database contexts; the ApplicationDbContext seen above and a different databaseEntites context that's used in my controllers. Could this be the source of the problem?

Comment: Can you check if `Admin` saved to your DB and user is associated correctly with this role

Comment: @shrug that did not work for probably different reasons. This is the correct answer - the main point `Roles.IsUserInRole` belongs to older framework and should not be used here.